# Regular Expression search/replace on columns with python pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

The following is a small example of a .csv file I'm trying to do some data manipulation on. Each "comment" column has a column of it's own, separated by a semil colon ("date;user;comment"). My goal is to prepend "gp-" to the user

Original:

```
issue_key,summary,comment,comment,comment,comment,resolution
ABC-1234,summary1,"03/11/2021 12:18;user1;a text comment","03/10/2021 11:18;user2,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-4321,summary2,"03/08/2021 12:10;user7;a text comment","03/10/2021 11:18;user5,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-2214,summary3,"03/09/2021 12:20;user9;a text comment",,"03/10/2021 11:18;user3,a text comment",,Unresolved
```

What I'd like it to be transformed to:

```
issue_key,summary,comment,comment,comment,comment,resolution
ABC-1234,summary1,"03/11/2021 12:18;gp-user1;a text comment","03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user2,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-4321,summary2,"03/08/2021 12:10;gp-user7;a text comment","03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user5,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-2214,summary3,"03/09/2021 12:20;gp-user9;a text comment",,"03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user3,a text comment",,Unresolved
```

The code I have so far. I think I'm close'ish:

```
with open(destination_filename) as f:
    orig_header = f.readline()
orig_header = orig_header.split(",")
orig_header[-1] = orig_header[-1].strip()
csv_data = pd.read_csv(destination_filename)
cols = csv_data.columns[csv_data.columns.str[:7]=='Comment']
csv_data[cols] = csv_data[cols].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d+\/\d+\/\d\d\d\d \d+:\d+);(\S+);(.*)', r'\1;gp-\2;\3', str(x)))
csv_data.to_csv(f"{destination_filename}", index = False, header=orig_header)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be just to use the built in `csv` library. It can also be used to process the comment fields as `;` separated csv rows.

For example:

```
import io
import csv

def replace_user(entry):
    if len(entry):
        values = next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(entry, newline=''), delimiter=';'))
        values[1] = f'gp-{values[1]}'
        entry = ';'.join(values)
    return entry


with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input)) # copy the header
    
    for row in csv_input:
        row[2:6] = [replace_user(v) for v in row[2:6]]
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` containing:

```
issue_key,summary,comment,comment,comment,comment,resolution
ABC-1234,summary1,03/11/2021 12:18;gp-user1;a text comment,"03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user2,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-4321,summary2,03/08/2021 12:10;gp-user7;a text comment,"03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user5,a text comment",,,Unresolved
ABC-2214,summary3,03/09/2021 12:20;gp-user9;a text comment,,"03/10/2021 11:18;gp-user3,a text comment",,Unresolved
```

If comments can also have quotes or newlines, an additional `csv.writer()` could be used instead of the `join()`.